# AES-ECB block-decryption in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I wrote code that decrypts the input string completely. But since this is an ECB mode, I wanted to somehow decrypt not the entire input text, but only a separate block of it.

As far as I understand, ECB AES encrypts in blocks of 8 bytes. How can I add the `AES_Decrypt` function to it so that it decrypts only the last 8 bytes of the input string, for example.

```
    byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = new byte[32];

    byte[] 8_bytesToBeDecrypted = new byte[8];  // Only 8 bytes of bytesToBeDecrypted

    public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            string salt = "12345678";
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
            byte[] saltBytes = unicode.GetBytes(salt);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;
                    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 65535);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return decryptedBytes;
        }
```

Comment: AES has 16-byte block size. You use Rijndael and Rijndael != AES.

Comment: But the AES control examples matched what I got using Rijndael

Comment: AES has a fixed block size of 128 bits and a key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits, whereas Rijndael can be specified with block and key sizes in any multiple of 32 bits, with a minimum of 128 bits and a maximum of 256 bits.

Comment: If you use 8-byte for encryption, the rest is padding. And you use PaddingMode.Zeros that fills the rest with 0s

Comment: Thanks! And using Rijndael instead of AES loses in the speed of work? And as far as I understand Rijndael is just more general than AES?

Comment: Yes, Rijndael is more general but not the standard, AES is the standard. For secure implementations, I don't think that nobody works on Rijndael anymore. You can find AES in CPUs it is called AES-NI in INTEL. See OpenSSL speed test with `evp` enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely just [`Seek` the `MemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.seek?view=netframework-4.8) with a multiple of 16 bytes from the beginning (or apparently even 16 bytes from the last part of the stream) and *then* connect the `CryptoStream` to decrypt whatever is left. With CBC that would be a bit more tricky as you would have to set the IV to the previous ciphertext block, but with ECB this should be a breeze.

---

Notes:

- Of course, you don't need to set the IV for the ECB mode, that should not be required.
- Rijndael with a block size of 128 is actually AES. C#/.NET only supports a subset of Rijndael by the way: only 64 increments of the block size and key size are supported, if I remember correctly.
- I'd still use [`aes = Aes.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes.create?view=netframework-4.8) rather than `aes = new RijndaelManaged()` as that leaves the choice of the AES implementation to the system, and it will probably choose the hardware accelerated one over the managed one.